# Invalid action configuration BuildArtif not found - AWS code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to setup pipeline for my project. For the first time everything worked fine. All three phases were successfully working and code also uploaded on S3 bucket.

After that for next change I clicked on "Release Changes" button to re-deploy. Now I have started receiving this error that says 'Invalid action configuration'

```
The input artifact, codepipeline-us-east-1-685916803168/*******/BuildArtif/2i3YMym, does not exist or you do not have permissions to access it: 
The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; 
Request ID: K2CW6Z1J5XEX7PK6; S3 Extended Request ID: JxPXyzOz9ue2eonVYEKMBwyEZvV+F4WNAdCry0XBRmJNtt24NCnZzAd43vTL4QqUZWZgAr2UrjE=; Proxy: null)
```

[image]

I even deleted the pipeline and created from scratch but still same error.

My S3 bucket is publicly accessible and also has the policy added

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awesome-bucket-name*"
        }
    ]
}
```

===========================

I found that in the bucket where artifact files are placed, particular folder `BuildArtif` is missing.For some reason BuildArtif is not being created in mentioned bucket. It has to store in bucket so that during deployment it can be access from there. But that artifact file missing it causing this error. I have only 3 phases. `Source, Build and Deploy`. `SourceArtif` I can see it in bucket but not `BuildArtif`.

Source and Build phased should generate those artificat everytime they are triggered. So I can see SourceArtif but not BuildArtif.

I am not able to debug why BuildAritf folder is missing.

Kindly help.

My buildspec:

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    APP_NAME: "project-name"
    CACHE_CONTORL : "86400"
    S3_BUCKET: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/test1.project-name.com/"
    BUILD_FOLDER: "project-name-ng/dist/project-name/browser"
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 14.x
    commands:
      - echo install process started
      - npm install -g @angular/cli
      - cd project-name-ng
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo build process started now
      - ng build --configuration=production
      - echo build process finished, we should uplload to S3 now
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo uploading...
      - cd dist/project-name/browser
      - ls -la
    files:
      - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'dist/project-name/browser*'
    discard-paths: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `buildspec.yaml` should have the `artifacts` section inside to have your **BuildArtifacts** available on your S3 bucket. Here is my example where I prepare my `hello.json` file.

```
version: 0.2
env:
  # ANY
phases:
  # ANY
  post_build:
      - printf '{"hello":"world"}' > hello.json
artifacts:
  files:
    - ./hello.json
  discard-paths: yes
```

Once done, you can observe your **Build** stage with **Artifacts** details as per screenshot.

[image: codebuild-artifacts-s3-details]

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html

Try adding this and re-deploy again to see the next messages/errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Binh for pointing out mistake in my buildspec.

After adding `artifacts` key and making some adjustment to path it finally worked. Below is the modified buildspec, if anybody came accross.

Since my git has some nested folder I had to mentioned relative path from root of my git.

### updated build spec

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    APP_NAME: "project_name"
    CACHE_CONTORL : "86400"
    S3_BUCKET: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/test1.project_name.com/"
    BUILD_FOLDER: "project_name-ng/dist/project_name/browser"
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 14.x
    commands:
      - echo install process started
      - npm install -g @angular/cli
      - cd project_name-ng
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo build process started now
      - ng build --configuration=production
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo build process finished, we should uplload to S3 now

artifacts:
    files:
      - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'project_name-ng/dist/project_name/browser*'
    discard-paths: yes
```